# Style from next sibling element not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make visual effects on my page. If the user hovers on the div `image-container`, the text in the next next sibling element `image-hover`, must be visible. But it doesn't. Can anyone look to my code?

```js
var cats = document.getElementsByClassName('image-container');
var lengte = cats.length;

for (var i = 0; i < lengte; i++) {

    cats[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        var el = this.nextSibling.nextSibling; // this I do because the next sibling 
                                               // element is text.
        el.style = 'display: block !importent';
    });
}
```

```css
#img1 {
    transition: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    -o-transform: scale(0.7);
    top: -100px;
    left: -90px;
}

img.clipped {
    position: relative;
}

.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 411px;
}

.image-hover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<article class="col-lg-3 categorie">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz8tG.jpg" class="clipped" id="img1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image-hover">
        <h2><a href="/Topic?categorie=7&page=1">Wintersport</a></h2>
        <p class="inhoud">Hou je van koude winters en sport? Dan is deze categorie zeker iets voor u! Hier kan je verschillende artikelen lezen van personen die verbleven op een winter ski oord. Je vind er ook vershillende indoor ski- en snowboard pistes.</p>
        <hr />
        <p><b>Top vijf hot items</b></p>
        <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Topic/Details?activiteit=24683">
                        <span class="punten">0,5</span>
                        test41
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Topic/Details?activiteit=24676">
                        <span class="punten">0,5</span>
                        test34
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Topic/Details?activiteit=24666">
                        <span class="punten">0,4</span>
                        test24
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Topic/Details?activiteit=24696">
                        <span class="punten">0,3</span>
                        test53
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Topic/Details?activiteit=24670">
                        <span class="punten">0,3</span>
                        test28
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here is also a result from debugging my code.

[image]

Comment: `this.nextSibling.nextSibling` is a prone error approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
el.style = 'display: block !importent';
```

there's a typo in your code

Replace `importent` with `important`